# download file via powershell script with authentication through our firewall

Tags: powershell, script, firewall, authentication

i need a powershell script to download a file from a website. 
we normaly need to open a browser first and authenticate to a website.
how can i do this through an unintended script.
thanks

i have tried several versions of scripts online but no luck..

```
$source = "http://chocolatey.org/install.ps1"
$dest = "C:\temp\chocolatey_install.ps1"
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebProxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy("http://chocolatey.org:8080",$true)
#$WebProxy.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential("user","password","domain.local")
$WebProxy.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential("$user","$password","")
$WebClient.Proxy = $WebProxy
$WebClient.DownloadFile($source,$dest)
```

Comment: So your script doesn't work? What are the symptoms? What are the error messages? Please [edit] the question to include this vital information.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should send the Authorization header yourself, like this (untested) code:

```
$uri = "{url here}"
$username = "{username here}"
$password = "{password here}"
$b = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username + ":" + $password)
$p = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($b)
$creds = "Basic " + $p
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{"Accept" = "*/*"; "Authorization" = $creds}
```